# Difference between cookie and cookieSession?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

What is the difference between `cookieSession` and `cookie` in Express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`cookieParser` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) parses HTTP `Cookie:` headers to populate `req.cookies` (and `req.signedCookies` if you give it a secret).

The [`cookieSession` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html) adds cookie-based session state.
It depends on the `cookieParser` middleware to use cookies.

There is no `cookie` middleware, although there is a [`cookie` package](https://npmjs.org/package/cookie) which exposes a utility function that creates or parses cookie strings.  The `cookieParser` middleware uses this package to read & write HTTP headers.

Comment: what does `cookie` allow me to do that `cookieSession` does not and vice versa?

Comment: @gilbertbw: They do two completely different things.  Read the documentation.